# using jquery to clone an element with lots of dynamic attributes

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a type of photo album for a site.  The user can upload images.  When an image is uploaded via jquery upload (ajax call) the server is going to some information that is dynamic:

1. image path
2. image id

The image id especially will be used in several places within the object I need to clone:

```
        <div class="photoContainer" id=
"photo_clone">
           <form ajaxify="/ajax/photos/metadata/save/" class="editablePhoto" id="**PHOTOID**" data-photoid="**PHOTOID**" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="">
              <div class="photoWrap editablePhotoReady">
                 <div class="letterboxedImage photo editablePhotoImage verticallyCentered" style="height:194px;">
                    <div class="uiScaledImageContainer scaledImage" style="width: 290px; height: 193px; margin-top: -96px;">
                          <img class="scaledImageFitWidth" src="**PHOTO_URL**" width="288" height="194" alt="">
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="inputs">
                  <div class="captionArea2">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <textarea class="uiTextareaNoResize uiTextareaAutogrow captionTextarea mentionsTextarea textInput DOMControl_placeholder" title="Say something about this photo..." name="caption_text" placeholder="Say something about this photo..." role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="js_34" onkeydown="" aria-label="Say something about this photo..." style="height: 55px; ">Say something about this photo...</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
              </div>   
              <div class="metadataControls">
                 <div class="inner uiBoxGray"><span data-photo="**PHOTOID**" class="metaIcon deleteIcon"></span><span data-photo="**PHOTOID**" class="metaIcon locationIcon"></span><span class="metaIcon photoState"><i>Pending approval</i></span></div>
              </div>
           </form>
            </div> <!--photo id div-->
```

If I'm cloning this object, is there some type of jquery function I can use to do something like 'clone this, and when you clone it replace these placeholders in the cloned object with this parameter map I'm going to pass you'.  Something like:

```
clone(myHtmlToClone, map['imageId': '12345', 'imagePath':'www.domain.com/image/fjeeirefjdf.gif'])
```

where all occurrences of 'imageId' in myHtmlToClone would be replaced with '12345', and the imagePath would be replaced with 'www.domain.com/image/fjeeirefjdf.gif'.  This is assuming I defined placeholders in the html.  In the html code above it's just the raw, non-dynamic html.

EDIT IDEAS:

Idea #1
Using find (example taken from another code snippet, does not match HTML tags described above)

```
var clone = $("#my_clone").clone()

        clone.find("input[id$=id]")
                .attr('id',htmlId + 'id')
                .attr('name',htmlId + 'id');

        clone.find("input[id$=deleted]")
                .attr('id',htmlId + 'deleted')
                .attr('name',htmlId + 'deleted');

        clone.find("input[id$=new]")
                .attr('id',htmlId + 'new')
                .attr('name',htmlId + 'new')
                .attr('value', 'true');

        clone.find("select[id*='favoriteQuestion']")
                .attr('id', htmlId + 'favoriteQuestion.id')
                .attr('name', htmlId + 'favoriteQuestion.id');

        $("#childList").append(clone);
        clone.show();
```

Idea #2:

```
var clone = $("#my_clone").clone()

    clone.replace('**PHOTOID**', photoId).replace('**PHOTO_URL**', photoUrl);
```

EDIT: Working Answer:

```
function addPhoto(photoId) {
    var clone = $("#photo_clone").clone()

    clone.find("img[id$=id]")
        .attr('id', 'photo_' + photoId)
        .attr('name', 'photo_' + photoId);

    clone.find('*[data-photoid="clone.id"]')
        .attr('data-photoid', photoId);

    clone.attr('id', 'photo_' + photoId);
    $("#photoList").append(clone);
    clone.show();
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "placeholders".  I wrote a whole answer assuming you meant properties on the cloned object, but now it appears that maybe you meant something different.  And, are you passing in raw HTML?  If so, that isn't really a clone as much as it as template.

Comment: Also, I can't tell where imageId and imagePath should go in your sample HTML.

Comment: And, is your source HTML in string form or a set of DOM objects already created?

Comment: Yeah, look at JS templating languages, like handlebars

Comment: I've updated the HTML with the placeholders in ALL CAPS.  The photo id is replaced in multiple places, the image path once.  I've also included a couple ideas.  I'm not sure if #2 works, since clone is the DOM element and not a string.  The source HTML is not a string, but a hidden div at the end of the document, so it's part of the DOM and can be clonsed.

Comment: I've added some code that I got to work.  I'm not sure if it is the most efficient choice or clean choice.